# Java mailto to MIME

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime, mailto, rfc2368

Looking for a Java library to convert a mailto link to a MIME message, or at least fill in the parts of it that are contained within the mailto link.  Only solution I've found (an SO question) involves use of `Desktop` which I'm pretty sure my application cannot depend on (highly concurrent, running on a web server).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Most users who surf your web site will have their web browser configured to open their mail client with the information from the mailto: link pre-filled in the composition window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell something simple does not exist.  The following code worked using the `Uri` class from Android, which was not complicated to excise from the Android libraries:

```
MailTo mailTo = MailTo.parse(unsubscribeUrl);

        Map<String, String> headers = mailTo.getHeaders();
        Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> values = headers.entrySet();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : values) {
            message.addHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
        }
```